# Round an integer contained within a String without converting it to an Int/Double/Float/Decimal?

Tags: swift, rounding

So I am trying to round a number (which is input as a `String`) that is *possibly* larger than Swift’s integer size limit to the nearest hundredth. With decimal cases like .999, this could potentially involve changing the content before the decimal point. I do not want to have to convert this string into an integer as, because of its potential size, that might cause an error.

How would I go about adding 1 to an integer **contained within a string** (eg. “299” -> 300) without ever converting it to a decimal/float/int/double?

I have tried using the built-in round function but it does not work in my case.

Comment: I see the issue with using `Decimal`, but why not `Double` or `Decimal`? Both of them have a *massive* range

Comment: If this is not homework, then i'd just use something like [`BigInt`](https://github.com/attaswift/BigInt)

Comment: I need high precision even with numbers with 75 or more digits, so using a Double or Decimal is not really feasible.